# Testing Application in Android Studio with Roboelectric

Tags: android, unit-testing

I need to testing for my application using Roboelectric with AndroidStudio,integration of Roboelectric is over,now i have to
network calls for which i used Spring.io,i need to test services,BroadcastReceivers and Views.

Please Suggest me some links or books,i already searched for that i didnot get documentation for Roboelectric.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is not much documentation about Robolectric. I had to search for examples all over the internet.

The official [Robolectric site](http://robolectric.org/) is a good way to start . Also the [Robolectric blog](http://robolectric.blogspot.mx/) has really nice examples . But what I found really helpful was [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEklodQTJZY) . Colin Miller makes it look so simple.

I'm still looking for a book or something more formal, so to speak. So if you find something please let me know, I'll do the same. cheers!